# Qual a real complexidade por traz do Sleep Sort em comparação aos demais?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Sei que esta é a minha primeira pergunta aqui no stackoverflow em português. No entanto senti a falta de menção a este algoritmo chamado **sleep-sort**.

Pelo que sei a origem dele é "supostamente" desconhecida pois não se sabe o autor. Procede?

Aliás raramente este algoritmo de ordenação é citado em comparação dos outros (**quick-sort**, **bubble-sort**, etc...). É questão de popularidade ou procedência?

E principalmente como citado no título, qual a complexidade algorítmica? E qual a diferença da versão *"tradicional"* e *"cancelável"*?

[Exemplos de códigos - Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Sleep_sort)

Comment: Não conhecia esse algoritmo, mas achei meio anedótico. A maneira como ele funciona não me parece nada eficiente

Comment: Falta alguma coisa na minha resposta? Talvez eu possa completar se me falar.

Comment: Sim, faltou responder a última questão referente a versão "cancelável" ou interruptivo e o tradicional!!

Comment: E tem fontes disponíveis falando disso? Não achei em parte alguma. Parece até que inventaram essa expressão informalmente e ficou por isso mesmo, o que não me surpreenderia falando de algoritmos como esse. Acho que minha resposta é adequada, simplesmente se subentende que é um algoritmo abortável apesar das dificuldades de cessar cada thread.

Comment: Já comentei a sua resposta abaixo, com fontes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pelo que sei a origem dele é "supostamente" desconhecida pois não se sabe o autor. Procede?

Matheus, se não me engano este algoritmo tem sua primeira menção num relato de entrevista de emprego na Google com um candidato que não teve seu nome revelado (http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/11/linear-time-sort-puzzler.html). Essa história pode ser falsa ou talvez menções anteriores terem ocorrido e não termos encontrado. Não há muita materialidade.

> Aliás raramente este algoritmo de ordenação é citado em comparação dos outros (**quick-sort**, **bubble-sort**, etc...). É questão de popularidade ou procedência?

É questão de qualidade mesmo. Talvez também questão de didática. Outros algoritmos são mais adequados para se estudar e aprender algoritmos, já esse ao meu ver não passa de uma curiosidade da área da computação.

A ideia é criativa, mas quem usa pra valer? Nunca vi.

Normalmente usam-se algoritmos considerados melhores como insertion sort (bom em ordenações de sequências pequenas), quick sort (controvérsias devido ao pior caso), merge sort (controvérsias devido aos casos médios e melhores, bem como armazenamento adicional de dados) e tree sort (mais usado em construção de árvores de busca balanceadas, não como algoritmo de ordenação).

Normalmente quem quer algoritmos de ordenação de alto desempenho fazem uso de misturas de algoritmos conhecidos.

Por exemplo, se a sequência ordenado é pequena, usa-se insertion sort. Se não é tão pequena a ponto de compensar, usa-se iterações de quicksort para partir os trechos em subtrechos menores até insertion sort nesses subtrechos valerem a pena. Se a sequência for grande demais a ponto de não se desejar o risco de um comportamento no entorno do pior caso, usa-se heapsort até que se tenha disposição ao risco para aplicar o quicksort com insertion sort.

> E principalmente como citado no título, qual a complexidade algorítmica?

Depende do que quer dizer com complexidade. O termo genericamente se refere a dificuldades do algoritmo (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_computacional), ou melhor, custos da execução dele que pode ser em número de operações, tempo de execução, número de ciclos de loop e até mesmo demanda de recursos como dados armazenados (ou seja, memória necessária).

Tipo, quando se analisa algoritmos de ordenação por comparações, normalmente se leva em conta número de comparações e montante de dados adicionais. Por exemplo, merge sort tem complexidade de número de comparações O(n*log(n)) em melhores e piores casos (portanto médios também), seus dados adicionais têm complexidade dependente de como é implementado e em que tipo de estrutura, podendo ser de O(1) (em listas, por exemplo) ou O(n) (em arrays quando o algoritmo não faz "shift" nos elementos), ainda assim a complexidade de tempo pode ser igual ou pior que a de comparações dependendo de como se implementa.

No caso, sleep sort não é algoritmo de ordenação por comparação. Os critérios então são outros. A complexidade de número de threads é O(n) porque o número de threads é igual ao tamanho da sequência. A complexidade de instruções também é linear porque a cada elemento se tem uma iteração de loop com O(1) instruções chamando uma thread e mais tarde a thread executa também com O(1) instruções. A complexidade de memória demandada provavelmente é linear por ser proporcional ao número de threads. Enfim, inúmeros critérios lineares podem ser pensados, mas vou assumir que, na verdade, você quer saber a complexidade de tempo de execução.

Desprezando tempo de execução de instruções e overheads, o maior elemento da sequência vale o tempo em milissegundos esperados para ter o resultado completo, quer dizer O(n) sendo que "n" não é número de elementos mas sim o valor do máximo. Porém não só o aguardo do sleep define o verdadeiro tempo de execução. A percorrência no array, as chamadas de threads, as execuções delas, a concorrência entre elas pelos recursos de processamento, as atualizações de buffers de console e tudo mais também levam tempo e dependem do sistema operacional e da arquitetura, tudo isso podendo impactar na real complexidade. Além disso, esse algoritmo aparentemente foi pensado para sequências pequenas, afinal pode-se imaginar inúmeros problemas em chamar uma thread por elemento quando são muito numerosos. Resumindo, não existe complexidade de tempo.

Ainda assim, se quer forçar a barra você pode considerar o pior caso: sequência não crescente (decresce ou conserva em cada adjacência) de elementos grandes que variam entre eles de tal maneira que haja a concentração de todas as chamadas de threads num mesmo instante e sem paralelizar as threads, mas sem mais limitações como a de memória, possíveis erros de resultados, etc. O que acontecerá?

Primeiro, loop de complexidade O(T) com "T" igual ao tamanho da sequêcia. Depois, espera de complexidade O(M) com "M" igual ao último elemento, já que a espera do processador começa ao criar a thread dele e termina com todas as threads tendo que ser executadas juntamente com essa, que dormiu "M" milissegundos. Ao fim da espera, tratamento de concorrência de complexidade desconhecida O(D) com "D" de desconhecido e execução de threads com complexidade O(T).

E aí? O que faz com isso? Tempo linear com T mais tempo linear com M mais tempo linear com D mais tempo linear com T. Que complexidade é essa? Se não for considerar uma variável em função de outra, é O(T+M+D). Se for considerar que é tudo proporcional, é O(T) (ou se preferir O(M) ou O(D)). Se for considerar que "M" é quadrático em relação a "T" e cúbico em relação a "D", é O(T) ou O(M²) ou O(D³). Se desprezar "D" e assumir que os valores da sequência são limitados, tipo vão de 0 a 2³²-1 ou de 0 a 2⁶⁴-1, temos O(D) e O(M) ambos iguais a O(1) (por maior que seja o absurdo de esperar 2³²ms) e portanto a complexidade do algoritmo seria O(T). Daí em diante...

> E qual a diferença da versão *"tradicional"* e *"cancelável"*?

Não encontrei fontes abordando, mas encontrei discussões falando sobre abortar threads em sleep. Suponho que sleep sort cancelável é aquele que é implementado com a possibilidade de parar toda a ordenação durante o processo, mesmo tendo que fazer isso com cada thread. O tradicional, como podemos ver nos exemplos de código, são só um código em loop criando thread e dando sleep e outro com a impressão do valor ao terminar o sleep, sem nada que permita cessar todo o processo de ordenação.

Comment: Não se esqueça do [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (híbrido, mais recente, pior caso O(nlogn), e usado em Python, Java entre outros citados no link)

Comment: Pesquisei sobre, o assunto e parece que o algoritmo foi inventado como brincadeira por um membro do [4chan board - archive](https://archive.tinychan.net/read/prog/1295544154), [mais informações](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos226/lectures/52Tries.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

O sleep-sort não é nada eficiente, não parece ter uso no mundo real. Na [wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_sort) há um tópico sobre os problemas desse algoritmo:

> Baseando neste algoritmo (escrito em Python) o tempo de execução é `n+nx`, onde `x` é o maior número da lista de elementos, resultando na complexidade `O(n^2)` (com n ≥ x). No algoritmo original a complexidade é a mesma, embora o tempo de execução seja `n+nxt`, onde `t` é a constante de tempo (um segundo neste caso, devido ao funcionamento da função sleep). Outro possível modo de identificar a complexidade do algoritmo é verificar que ele é executado em tempo `O(n)` em n processadores, resultando em `O(n^2)`.
>
> Embora teoricamente correto, esse algoritmo não deve ser considerado utilizável em implementações reais por apresentar diversos problemas. O principal deles reside na condição de corrida que é inerente à sua implementação. Sem sombra de dúvidas, se os valores estiverem muito próximos um do outro, o algoritmo não é capaz de ordenar a lista satisfatóriamente, além disso, a premissa de que os dados sejam sempre positivos é uma premissa forte pois implica que o intervalo em que os dados estão compreendidos seja uma informação conhecida.

Vamos supor que você escolha usar um sleep em `ms` correspondente ao número, por exemplo no array [5, 6, 9, 1, 3], você colocaria um sleep de 5ms a para o primeiro elemento, 6ms para o segundo e assim sucessivamente. Para esse array você demoraria pelo menos 9ms para ordenar, que é o valor do maior elemento. Se no array tiver algum número grande, como 1.000.000, o tempo de ordenação seria mais de 16 minutos